# How to choose option in import data in sql

Tags: sql-server

I imported xls file to sql. I did following:

Right click on database-> task-> Import Data->....

But when I click to edit maping, I can't choose the third option "Append rows to destination table".

It just allows me to choose first option:"Create destination table".

I don't know what wrong with that.

Pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  The Column Mappings step only allows you to specify which columns will be on your destination table and what type/size they will be.

Because you are creating a new table, your data will be appended to the (empty) table by default.  That is why the option to append rows is disabled.  After you define your destination table, proceed with the next steps and it should load your data into the new table.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question. It's very simple.

From window "Select source Tables and Views", look column destination.

Choose row realtive with table which you want to map. Choose and map it to respond exist table.

It's Very simple

@PaulStock: thank for your answer but not right for me. I know just map when table exist. But I can choose how to map.